# Rails CSS loads, but style isn't applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I'm following the book http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails and my scss files aren't working.

The css file is this one:

```
.store {
  h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    font:  150% sans-serif;
    color: #226;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted #77d;
  }

  /* An entry in the store catalog */
  .entry {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #77d;
    min-height: 100px;

    img {
      width: 80px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      position: absolute;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin-left: 100px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      color: #227;
    }

    p, div.price_line {
      margin-left: 100px;
      margin-top: 0.5em; 
      margin-bottom: 0.8em; 
    }

    .price {
      color: #44a;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-right: 3em;
    }
  }
}
```

and the html file the following:

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="entry">
    <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %> 
    <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
    <p><%= sanitize(product.description) %></p>
    <div class="price_line">
      <span class="price"><%= product.price %></span>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The CSS is loading properly, but not being applied. However if add a surrounding div with the class "store" it works. The book doesn't refer this situation, and I believe it should "automatically" apply the style, right?

Thanks.

***EDIT*****************

I found the problem. For those who may encounter the same issue, check the file:

app/assets/views/layouts/application.html.erb

**body** tag should have the following code:

```
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great that you found out the solution. But im trying to explain what happened behind the scene.

The way you are using the css **is not a general convention**. This facility comes with some additional gem. Check this link **https://stackoverflow.com/a/4564922/1160106**. With these gems you are able to design your css more [**DRY**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way.

---

### General Convention

if you want to apply style to the following `h1` element

```
# Here "store" class is the parent element of "h1"
<div class="store">
     <h1> some text </h1>
</div>
```

Will require following way of css

```
#Here also "store" is written before "h1"
.store h1 
{ 
   #some designs
}
```

---

### Whats happening in your case?

Probably you are maintaining controller wise css files. And presuming that you have a `stores_controller`. Thats why the classes for your `stores_controller` is encapsulated in `.store {}` block. Like

```
.store {
    h3 {font-size: 120%;}
}
```

So it is clear that your `h3` elements require a parent element having `store` class. And you are doing so by adding `class="<%= controller.controller_name %>"` with your `body` tag. Undoubtedly the `<body>` tag is parent of all following nodes. Now when you are hitting `stores_controller` it sets `class="store"` and your styles are working.

The approach is really [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and recommendable.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I was aware this isn't normal css, and what was happening behind the scenes, however, since I am new to Rails, I didn't know how it worked in Rails. I just didn't know whether the class name should be somewhere or not. I suspected Rails "connected" somehow the stylesheet to this specific controller view. However, when I figured out the solution, I found out it was a lot more straightforward than I expected :)

Answer (score 0):

As per your code all the styling is between the `.store { }` block, so it will not reflect as long as you surrounding div with the class "store"

For example

```
.store {
  h3 {
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
}
```

is same as

```
.store h3 {
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin-left: 100px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      color: #227;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, like I said, if I add a surrounding div with store class, the style works. However, the book never refers this! I believe it should work without that.