# Could I target a class inside of CSS statement?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

Is it possible to do something similar to this in CSS:

```
.class1:checked + class2{
    .sidebar{
        color:blue;
    }
}
```

In the case of class1 being checked, look at it's sibling(class2) and change #sidebar's color to blue.

Comment: Try with SASS or LESS: http://lesscss.org/ http://sass-lang.com/ You can make things like this

Comment: Use `.class1:checked #sidebar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting CSS classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes)

Comment: `.class1:checked + class2 #sidebar {color:blue}` - this way it may work.

Comment: No, you cannot remote control the CSS of one element from some element in a different location.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can target a class inside of CSS statement by using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) features. First you should [Learn SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

**Nesting feature:**

**SCSS Syntax:**

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: *Yes you can do it*. Do what?

Comment: @torazaburo you're right. I correct it.

Answer (score 2):

in CSS you could do something like :

```
.class1:checked + .class2 > .sidebar {
   color : blue
}
```

If the checkbox with `class="class1"` is checked, `class="class2"` his child, `class="sidebar"` will adept the blue color.

Here is a working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVMoEZ)

Comment: This only works if `#sidebar` in the markup is inside `.class1`

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me this way!! Now it depends, how are you actually using your code, or how you have written your HTML.

```css
/* by default, next text is red */

.class2 {
  color: red;
}
/* if checked, next text is green */

.class1:checked + .class2 {
  color: green;
}
#sidebar {
  color: pink;
}
/* if checked, next text is blue and its child gets below CSS */

.class1:checked + .class2 #sidebar {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label for="check">we are trying to make your code work</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="class1">
<p class="class2">If the checkbox is checked, the next link SIDEBARLINK should have border of red color for demo purpose.
  <a href="#" id="sidebar">Sidebar Link</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Although we won't know until the OP posts his HTML, it is highly likely that the sidebar is a sidebar in a different location in the HTML, not underneath the element with `class2`.

Comment: he asked for child element, this is valid for that scenario! and if he is trying for a #sidebar element - somewhere out or on another section, then its not possible as well as his questions goes invalid

Comment: No, he did not ask for a child element. Where do you see that?

Comment: check the edited history, he removed that child text.

Comment: I cannot see what you are referring to in the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#sidebar` is in a different part of the HTML from `.class1` etc., then **no, you cannot do this**. CSS selectors are a sequence of element specifiers where each specifier is either below (child or descendant) or at the same level (following sibling) as the previous one, and the final one is the one targeted. You cannot randomly reach out and affect a different part of the HTML. The curly bracket notation you invented in an attempt to target the sidebar is not CSS, and although it looks a bit like SASS, which confused some of the people answering, is not SASS and no, SASS cannot magically do what CSS cannot. SASS is mere syntax sugar.