# Apply styles to grouped multiple child elements

Tags: css

If I have the following

```
.dark-theme .link {color:black;}
.dark-theme a {color:red;}
.dark-theme button {color:green;}
.dark-theme div {color:orange;}
.dark-theme .whatever {color:blue;}
.dark-theme .element {color:navyblue;}
.dark-theme .element2 {color:black;}
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
.dark-theme {
    .link {color:black;}
    a {color:red;}
    button {color:green;}
    div {color:orange;}
    .whatever {color:blue;}
    .element {color:navyblue;}
    .element2 {color:black;}
}
```

Group styles of child so I don't have to keep rewriting the parent before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting CSS classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes)

Answer (score 0):

@LGSon is correct - Sass or LESS will work very well for this, if you can use it. For example, your code will translate exactly how you wanted on [this demonstration website](http://sass.js.org/).

See [Nesting CSS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes) for more details.

EDIT: Added an example of using LESS to accomplish this.

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <div>World</div>
</div>

<style type="text/less">
div {
font-size: 2em;
span {color:green;};
div {color:blue;};
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.1/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```