# CSS define ID for all child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Hey all been trying to see if this is possible.

What I am looking to do is define an ID that all other elements will fall under. I dont really know what offical this would be called so its hard to google for it :o)

Example:

```
<div id="ContentArea"> 
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" pattern="@.+" required>
        <label>Twitter</label>
        <span>
            <svg class="twitter-svg" enable-background="new 0 0 56.693 56.693" height="56.693px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 56.693 56.693" width="56.693px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <path d="M52.837,15.065c-1.811,0.805-3.76,1.348-5.805,1.591c2.088-1.25,3.689-3.23,4.444-5.592c-1.953,1.159-4.115,2-6.418,2.454  c-1.843-1.964-4.47-3.192-7.377-3.192c-5.581,0-10.106,4.525-10.106,10.107c0,0.791,0.089,1.562,0.262,2.303  c-8.4-0.422-15.848-4.445-20.833-10.56c-0.87,1.492-1.368,3.228-1.368,5.082c0,3.506,1.784,6.6,4.496,8.412  c-1.656-0.053-3.215-0.508-4.578-1.265c-0.001,0.042-0.001,0.085-0.001,0.128c0,4.896,3.484,8.98,8.108,9.91  c-0.848,0.23-1.741,0.354-2.663,0.354c-0.652,0-1.285-0.063-1.902-0.182c1.287,4.015,5.019,6.938,9.441,7.019  c-3.459,2.711-7.816,4.327-12.552,4.327c-0.815,0-1.62-0.048-2.411-0.142c4.474,2.869,9.786,4.541,15.493,4.541  c18.591,0,28.756-15.4,28.756-28.756c0-0.438-0.009-0.875-0.028-1.309C49.769,18.873,51.483,17.092,52.837,15.065z"/>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </div>          
</div>
```

So instead of doing this for the above in CSS:

```
#ContentArea .input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0px;
}
#ContentArea .input-group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  font-family: 'Bubbler One', sans-serif;
  color: #55acee;
}
etc etc...
```

I would like to see if its possible to do this:

```
#ContentArea {
    .input-group {
      position: relative;
      margin: 25px 0px;
    }
    .input-group label {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s, color 0.3s;
      font-size: 20px;
      z-index: -1;
      font-family: 'Bubbler One', sans-serif;
      color: #55acee;
    }
    etc.. etc..
}
```

Notice how I defined **ContentArea** around all my "child" elements. However, as you probably have guessed by now - that does not work.

Is there something like this available for css?

Comment: You should checkout [sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3) for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Not possible with CSS, but with SASS/SCSS/LESS one can do stuff like that

Comment: The words you're looking for this are "nested css" and there's an answer in S.O. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes