# Nesting elements in css

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="m-card-with-icon">
   <div class="top bg-green">
      <img class="icon" src="images/img1.png"/>
      <h3>Title1</h3>
  </div>
  <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius rutrum aliquet.</p>

</div>
```

and I am trying to apply some css to the image.

When I try

```
.m-card-with-icon {
min-height: 244px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #fafafa;
color: #848484;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
position: relative;


   .top {
        min-height: 100px;
        line-height: 60px;
        padding: 20px 180px 20px 40px;
        text-transform: capitalize; 
        display: table;
        width: 100.5%;


        img.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
            top: 25px;
            width: 140px;
            height: 140px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }


   }

}
```

whatever style I apply to img.icon does not show up - the images remain left-aligned.

Is there a problem with how I am nesting css?

Comment: You can't nest CSS like that.  That's more like SASS or LESS, you'd need a preprocessor.

Comment: As Matt said, you can't use nesting in CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes

Comment: how can I rewrite it?

Comment: `.m-card-with-icon .top { ... }` and `.m-card-with-icon .top img.icon { ... }` ?

Comment: @Jonathan could you please post your comment as an answer so i could accept it

Comment: ElenaDBA I think john c. j.'s answer is pretty much that, so you could accept theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you want this:

(We don't use nesting. Instead, you can "simulate" nesting by put parent element before child: `.m-card-with-icon .top`).

```
.m-card-with-icon {
    min-height: 244px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #848484;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.m-card-with-icon .top {
    min-height: 100px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 180px 20px 40px;
    text-transform: capitalize; 
    display: table;
    width: 100.5%;
}

.m-card-with-icon .top img.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can nest using css, but rather use scss or sass or less.
if you use scss then it will become

```
.m-card-with-icon {
  min-height: 244px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #848484;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

   .top {
    min-height: 100px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 180px 20px 40px;
    text-transform: capitalize; 
    display: table;
    width: 100.5%;

      .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 25px;
        top: 25px;
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On another note, if you have control over the HTML, it would be ideal to use something like [SMACSS](https://smacss.com) or [BEM](http://getbem.com).

Instead of nesting, you'll find that if you scope your CSS to use a single, unique class for every specific node. If you use a name prefixing methodology you can keep your class names organized.

For example rather than `.m-card-with-icon top {}` you can target `.m-card-with-icon-top {}`

Nesting can create complicated [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) rules and performance problems and you may find that a flat CSS might make your CSS more object oriented and modular.