# How To Remove Underline of Angular Material Date Picker

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I want to remove underline of Date Picker.
[image]
By using inspect I did it but its not working by css. How can I do it by css

```
::ng-deep{
    &.mdc-line-ripple::after{
        border-bottom-style:none !important ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using regular CSS. Try to use:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-line-ripple::after {
  border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
}
```

**See more:**

- [Nesting CSS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes)